# Softlayer API place order return Package (835) requires a preset configuration error

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

When I used SoftLayer API to create CCI using flavor which specific CPU, ram and first disk, I could not attach the second disk as before.

And I paste process details:

1. create CCI by createObject and parameters is below:

   ```
   POST https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest.json
   {
       "parameters": [
           {
               "blockDeviceTemplateGroup": {
                   "globalIdentifier": "2aae2a36-76f3-4d2f-9881-e86fa15b040b"
               },
               "datacenter": {
                   "name": "dc02"
               },
               "dedicatedAccountHostOnlyFlag": false,
               "domain": "softlayer.com",
               "hostname": "server-ed-20171108-032526-888",
               "hourlyBillingFlag": true,
               "localDiskFlag": false,
               "networkComponents": [
                   {
                       "maxSpeed": 100
                   }
               ],
               "primaryBackendNetworkComponent": {
                   "networkVlan": {
                       "id": 12345678,
                       "networkSpace": "PRIVATE"
                   }
               },
               "primaryNetworkComponent": {
                   "networkVlan": {
                       "id": 12345676,
                       "networkSpace": "PUBLIC"
                   }
               },
               "privateNetworkOnlyFlag": false,
               "supplementalCreateObjectOptions": {
                   "flavorKeyName": "B1_4X8X25"
               }
           }
       ]
   }
   ```
2. Wait for provision finish
3. Request SoftLayer_Product_Package objects for placing order

   ```
   GET https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/{vmid}.json?objectMask=mask%5BprimaryBackendNetworkComponent%5BprimaryIpAddress%2C+networkVlan%5Bid%2Cname%2CvlanNumber%2CprimaryRouter%5D%2C+subnets%5Bnetmask%2CnetworkIdentifier%5D%5D%2C+primaryNetworkComponent%5BprimaryIpAddress%2C+networkVlan%5Bid%2Cname%2CvlanNumber%2CprimaryRouter%5D%2C+subnets%5Bnetmask%2CnetworkIdentifier%5D%5D%5D
   ```

   Softlayer returns two packages(I used firstly)

   ```
   [
       {
           "description": "Virtual Server Instance",
           "id": 46,
           "isActive": 1,
           "name": "Cloud Server",
           "type": {
               "keyName": "VIRTUAL_SERVER_INSTANCE"
           }
       },
       {
           "description": "Public Virtual Server",
           "id": 835,
           "isActive": 1,
           "name": "Public Virtual Server",
           "type": {
               "keyName": "VIRTUAL_SERVER_INSTANCE"
           }
       }
   ]
   ```
4. Request SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest getUpgradeItemPrices for finding upgrade item price for the second disk

   ```
   POST https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/{vmid}/getUpgradeItemPrices.json
   ```

   And get 167 item prices and choice first item match categoryCode and capacity.
5. Place order

   ```
   POST https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder.json
   Parameters:
   {
       "parameters": [
           {
               "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest_Upgrade",
               "packageId": 46,
               "prices": [
                   {
                       "categories": [
                           {
                               "categoryCode": "guest_disk1",
                               "id": 82,
                               "name": "Second Disk",
                               "quantityLimit": 0
                           }
                       ],
                       "currentPriceFlag": false,
                       "hourlyRecurringFee": 0.013,
                       "id": 112953,
                       "item": {
                           "attributes": [
                               {
                                   "attributeType": {
                                       "keyName": "SAN_DISK",
                                       "name": "SAN Disk"
                                   },
                                   "id": 196,
                                   "itemAttributeTypeId": 50,
                                   "itemId": 922,
                                   "value": "1"
                               }
                           ],
                           "capacity": 100,
                           "description": "100 GB (SAN)",
                           "id": 922,
                           "itemTaxCategoryId": 166,
                           "keyName": "GUEST_DISK_100_GB_SAN_3",
                           "localDiskFlag": false,
                           "units": "GB"
                       },
                       "itemId": 922,
                       "laborFee": 0,
                       "locationGroupId": 505,
                       "oneTimeFee": 0,
                       "pricingLocationGroup": {
                           "description": "Location Group 3",
                           "id": 505,
                           "locationGroupType": {
                               "name": "PRICING"
                           },
                           "locationGroupTypeId": 82,
                           "locations": [
                               {
                                   "id": 449600,
                                   "longName": "Mexico 1",
                                   "name": "mex01",
                                   "statusId": 2
                               },
                               {
                                   "id": 2124095,
                                   "longName": "London 6",
                                   "name": "lon06",
                                   "statusId": 2
                               },
                               {
                                   "id": 167094,
                                   "longName": "London 1",
                                   "name": "lon01",
                                   "statusId": 2
                               },
                               {
                                   "id": 358694,
                                   "longName": "London 2",
                                   "name": "lon02",
                                   "statusId": 2
                               },
                               {
                                   "id": 2017395,
                                   "longName": "London 4",
                                   "name": "lon04",
                                   "statusId": 2
                               },
                               {
                                   "id": 1541257,
                                   "longName": "Oslo 1",
                                   "name": "osl01",
                                   "statusId": 2
                               }
                           ],
                           "name": "Location Group 3"
                       },
                       "recurringFee": 7.98,
                       "setupFee": 0,
                       "sort": 0
                   }
               ],
               "properties": [
                   {
                       "name": "MAINTENANCE_WINDOW",
                       "value": "2017-11-08T03:34:12Z"
                   },
                   {
                       "name": "NOTE_GENERAL",
                       "value": "Upgrade instance configuration."
                   }
               ],
               "virtualGuests": [
                   {
                       "id": {vmid}
                   }
               ]
           },
           false
       ]
   }
   ```

   This request get error with `Response:  {"error":"Invalid data on the order for property: packageId. Package (835) requires a preset configuration.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Order_InvalidData"}`

The request is that I used package '46' to upgrade, but Softlayer return error about package '835'. What is that meaning?

Comment: And I used package '835' to post placeOrder return the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding the property "presetId" in your request with a value = 0, also the packageId set it to 0. e.g.

```
POST https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder.json
Parameters:
{
    "parameters": [
        {
            "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest_Upgrade",
            "packageId": 0,
            "presetId": 0,
            "prices": [
                {
                    "categories": [
                        {
                            "categoryCode": "guest_disk1",
                            "id": 82,
                            "name": "Second Disk",
                            "quantityLimit": 0
                        }
                    ],
                    "currentPriceFlag": false,
                    "hourlyRecurringFee": 0.013,
                    "id": 112953,
                    "item": {
                        "attributes": [
                            {
                                "attributeType": {
                                    "keyName": "SAN_DISK",
                                    "name": "SAN Disk"
                                },
                                "id": 196,
                                "itemAttributeTypeId": 50,
                                "itemId": 922,
                                "value": "1"
                            }
                        ],
                        "capacity": 100,
                        "description": "100 GB (SAN)",
                        "id": 922,
                        "itemTaxCategoryId": 166,
                        "keyName": "GUEST_DISK_100_GB_SAN_3",
                        "localDiskFlag": false,
                        "units": "GB"
                    },
                    "itemId": 922,
                    "laborFee": 0,
                    "locationGroupId": 505,
                    "oneTimeFee": 0,
                    "pricingLocationGroup": {
                        "description": "Location Group 3",
                        "id": 505,
                        "locationGroupType": {
                            "name": "PRICING"
                        },
                        "locationGroupTypeId": 82,
                        "locations": [
                            {
                                "id": 449600,
                                "longName": "Mexico 1",
                                "name": "mex01",
                                "statusId": 2
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 2124095,
                                "longName": "London 6",
                                "name": "lon06",
                                "statusId": 2
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 167094,
                                "longName": "London 1",
                                "name": "lon01",
                                "statusId": 2
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 358694,
                                "longName": "London 2",
                                "name": "lon02",
                                "statusId": 2
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 2017395,
                                "longName": "London 4",
                                "name": "lon04",
                                "statusId": 2
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 1541257,
                                "longName": "Oslo 1",
                                "name": "osl01",
                                "statusId": 2
                            }
                        ],
                        "name": "Location Group 3"
                    },
                    "recurringFee": 7.98,
                    "setupFee": 0,
                    "sort": 0
                }
            ],
            "properties": [
                {
                    "name": "MAINTENANCE_WINDOW",
                    "value": "2017-11-08T03:34:12Z"
                },
                {
                    "name": "NOTE_GENERAL",
                    "value": "Upgrade instance configuration."
                }
            ],
            "virtualGuests": [
                {
                    "id": {vmid}
                }
            ]
        },
        false
    ]
}
```

let me know if that fix your issue.

Comment: I set that both 'packageId' and 'presetId' are 0, it return same error. What is the two zero value meaning?

Comment: please try removing those values (packageId and Presete)and let me know if the issue is still presetId

Comment: also please try setting setting the presetId value to 223, the presetID means the flavor that you picked out to order your VSI, I had understood this was not neccesary, but it seems that it is. You can get the preset that you used for the VSI like this GET https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/{VSIID}/getObject?objectMask=mask[id,billingItem[id,orderItem[presetId]]]

Comment: what is packageId with presetId 223? 0 or 223? It still returned the same mistake when removing or 223.

Comment: So the error is told that the 835 package need a persetId, but we never specified the 835 package. Why it returned that error?

Comment: Thank you. I check presetI‌d by getObject method you told. And the correct 'presetId' is another number: 215. And I checked CCI created by specifying memory/CPU/First_disk had null value of 'presetId'. I think this can tell if flavor is used or not. Continue to go down, the second disk doesn't contain a valid partition table.